# How to create a blog on nodejs(with express.js)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, blogs, backend

guys. Please, help me.

How to create a blog on NodeJS namely on ExpressJS (with basic funct. - delete/add/remove posts and comments, standard auth) ?

I did searched, and... I find a tutorials, but not a full.
And blog need for practic with nodejs, its a test, and little dream :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can checkout [mean.js](http://www.meanjs.org). It is a fullstack javascript framework that lets you generate crud modules (articles for your blogs) and more.